# Where Is The MYSQL Settings File Located On A Windows Installation

Tags: mysql

I need to set "lower_case_table_names", but I don't have any idea where to start.  I'm using XAMPP and I don't know where to look for the file or that the exact name of the file is.  One source said my.cnf another said my.conf, but neither of those files exist on my drive.  Is it possible I need to create such a file?  And if so, what folder must I put it in for the settings to take?

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess - you're running Windows, aren't you? If that's the case, go to your MySQL installation folder and locate `my.ini`. On my Windows XP box, this is `E:\Program Files\MySQL Server 5.1`.

You could as well create `my.cnf` and it would be picked up by MySQL, but it is best if only a single file is used. Check [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-create-option-file.html) for more details.

Possible values for `lower_case_table_names` are explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).